# can you simplify values in a monoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, monoid

Assume I have a monoid $M$  and I am not guaranteed that all elements have an inverse.

Say I have the property that:

$a^m = a^{m+n}$

Can I claim than it must be that $i=a^n$?

Why or why not?

Comment: One reason to think about why this is not be true in general is if you have function $f$ a map from $\mathbb{R}^2}$ to itself defined by $f(x,y) = (x,0)$ you have that $f = f \circ f$ but that does not mean that $f$ is the identity map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you cannot simplify expressions in monoids this way. Consider a monoid $M = \{i,x\}$, where $i$ is the neutral element and $x$ satisfies $x^2=x$. Then, $x^m=x^{n+m}$ for $n,m \geq 1$, but $i \neq x^n$.

However, in some monoids you can do this (for example, in groups and submonoids of groups).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no** : take in $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ with the regular matrix multiplication
$$ A= \left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}
 \right)$$
$$ A^{m+n}=A^m \neq I , \qquad \forall m,n>0$$

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes, if the monoid is a [cancellative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property) monoid.

Here's an example of a non-cancellative monoid under multiplication: $$\{[1],[4]\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$$

$[4][4]=[4]$, but $[4]\neq [1]$

Comment: So not true in general